# fade-in effect for a foreground image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Trying to do some CSS3 transitions and animations using 2 images.
Our requirement is

1. First display the background image
2. Move it slightly on the northward direction
3. Display the background image for few seconds (pause effect)
4. After few seconds introduce the foreground image (fade in effect)
5. Slightly move the image in northward direction
6. Fade out the foreground image

But we are unable to achieve the above exactly. Currently the background and foreground image are moving almost at the same time, unable to achieve the 'fade in' effect for the foreground image.

Demo Link: https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepskm/kLtyssjc/

Please help us out.

Our code

**HTML5 Code**

```
<div id="a" class="animated slideInUp">
    <div id="b" class="animated slideInUpChild">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-easy/512/535106-user_512x512.png" width="150px" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS3 Code**

```
#a
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2013/11-sea-beach-sand-wallpaper.jpg);
}

#b
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.animated
{
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.slideInUp
{
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
  animation-name: slideInUp;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.slideInUpChild
{
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes slideInUp
{
  from
  {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to
  {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp
{
  from
  {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to
  {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInUpChild
{
  from
  {
    bottom: 0;
  }

  to
  {
    bottom: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInUpChild
{
  from
  {
    bottom: 0;
  }

  to
  {
    bottom: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did that answer help you? If it did not, please [edit] and add more information into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by doing the following changes:

- Set initial `opacity` of the element that contains the image as `0` because it needs to fade-in later.
- To make sure that the foreground image fades-in and moves up a few seconds after background image has appeared and taken its position, add a delay that is more than `animation-duration` of the background image. Here, I have set it as `2s`. (I have also increased `animation-duration` of the foreground image to make the effect more visible but that is optional).
- Within the keyframes setting for the foreground image, make the initial state as `opacity: 0` and `bottom: 150px` (this is equal to the height of the image).
- Since there are 3 stages of animation for the foreground image (that is, the fade-in, the move and the fade-out), set the splits as `33%`, `66%` and `100%`.
- At `33%` change its `opacity` alone to `1` while `bottom` position remains the same. This produces the fade-in effect.
- At `66%` retain the `opacity` as `1` but change the `bottom` position as required. This means that the image moves-up while still being visible.
- At `100%`, retain the `bottom` position as-is but change the `opacity` to `0`. This makes it fade-out.

**Modified CSS:**

```css
.slideInUpChild {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes slideInUpChild {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 150px;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 150px;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

```css
#a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2013/11-sea-beach-sand-wallpaper.jpg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.slideInUp {
  animation-name: slideInUp;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.slideInUpChild {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideInUpChild {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 150px;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 150px;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="animated slideInUp">
  <div id="b" class="animated slideInUpChild">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-easy/512/535106-user_512x512.png" width="150px" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```